# Amazon API does not always return product values.

Tags: wordpress, amazon-product-api

I'm building a site on Wordpress which is going to be using Amazon API to grab price, title and image link after inputing Amazon ASIN.

I got it working with the script I have found (pasted below) but it works only about 5 out of 6 times. Every so often the API returns price as 0.00 and empty title and image link.

Is there something I am missing? I was prepared to use CRON job to auto update products on my website periodically but with this bug some products will be pretty much "reset" to 0.00 price.

Any help would be appreciated.

code here:

```
    <?php

        $amazon_asin = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'amazon_asin', true);
        $response = getAmazonPrice("co.uk", $amazon_asin);

    function getAmazonPrice($region, $asin) {

        $xml = aws_signed_request($region, array(
            "Operation" => "ItemLookup",
            "ItemId" => $asin,
            "IncludeReviewsSummary" => False,
            "ResponseGroup" => "Medium,OfferSummary",
        ));

        $item = $xml->Items->Item;
        $title = htmlentities((string) $item->ItemAttributes->Title);
        $url = htmlentities((string) $item->DetailPageURL);
        $image = htmlentities((string) $item->MediumImage->URL);
        $price = htmlentities((string) $item->OfferSummary->LowestNewPrice->Amount);
        $code = htmlentities((string) $item->OfferSummary->LowestNewPrice->CurrencyCode);
        $qty = htmlentities((string) $item->OfferSummary->TotalNew);

        if ($qty !== "0") {
            $response = array(
                "code" => $code,
                "price" => number_format((float) ($price / 100), 2, '.', ''),
                "image" => $image,
                "url" => $url,
                "title" => $title
            );
        }

        return $response;
    }

    function getPage($url) {

        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $html = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return $html;
    }

    function aws_signed_request($region, $params) {

        $public_key = get_option('public_key');
        $private_key = get_option('private_key');

        $method = "GET";
        $host = "ecs.amazonaws." . $region;
        $host = "webservices.amazon." . $region;
        $uri = "/onca/xml";

        $params["Service"] = "AWSECommerceService";
        $params["AssociateTag"] = get_option('associate_tag'); // Put your Affiliate Code here
        $params["AWSAccessKeyId"] = $public_key;
        $params["Timestamp"] = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");
        $params["Version"] = "2011-08-01";

        ksort($params);

        $canonicalized_query = array();
        foreach ($params as $param => $value) {
            $param = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($param));
            $value = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($value));
            $canonicalized_query[] = $param . "=" . $value;
        }

        $canonicalized_query = implode("&", $canonicalized_query);

        $string_to_sign = $method . "\n" . $host . "\n" . $uri . "\n" . $canonicalized_query;
        $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $string_to_sign, $private_key, True));
        $signature = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($signature));

        $request = "http://" . $host . $uri . "?" . $canonicalized_query . "&Signature=" . $signature;
        $response = getPage($request);


        var_dump($response);

        $pxml = @simplexml_load_string($response);
        if ($pxml === False) {
            return False;// no xml
        } else {
            return $pxml;
        }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems to be a problem with Amazon Product API. If you make the same request several times, then it should either always work or not work at all.

You can ask on Amazon Product API forums about the problem: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=9

You can also update your code so it does not update the product price if the title is missing from Amazon API response